# Protractor: element not interactable

Tags: protractor

My test is failing due to error:

> element not interactable  Failed: element not interactable
>         (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Some info
selenium standalone 3.141.59
geckodriver v0-26.0
Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)
This part of the code is for a non angular page.

As you can see on the code below, I added browser.sleep(), what didn't solve my problem
The element causing the problem is on the last line (id('column_header_44)

```
  it('should compare the space size stored, against the value stored in app', function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.className('designer-client-frame')).getWebElement());
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('div:nth-child(1) > .ms-Link > .ms-navbar-node-caption > span')).click();//click in Item
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('.horizontal-flex-container-item-layout--paigVxanvxFrIsRy2U02r:nth-child(3) .thm-head-a2-font-size-1--medflat > span')).click();//click in process
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('.ms-ContextualMenu-item:nth-child(1) .thm-popp-a2-font-stack-2--minflat')).click();//click in Time phased
        browser.sleep(3000);
       element(by.id('column_header_44')).click();//click on item no
        browser.sleep(3000);

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `browser.sleep` as an explicit waiting method. Use Protractor specific methods instead.
A good way to use a wait before that click would be to wait until the element is present in the html DOM (`presenceOf`), then wait for it to be clickable (`elementToBeClickable`), and finally, execute the clicking action:

```
it('should compare the space size stored, against the value stored in app', async () => {
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    const your_element = element(by.id('column_header_44'));

    await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(your_element));
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(your_element));
    await your_element.click();
});
```

Comment: Hi, @JoaquinCasco  thank you for your advice. I changed the code exactly like you suggested to me. But now I got an error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.  Just a remark,  I am working with 2 pages simultaneously, the first one is Angular and the second one (which I am having this issue) is non angular.

Comment: I used something like this : jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000000;        this is to write at the start of your tests

Answer (score 0):

It gives such an error because it does not see the button on the screen. it has to be clicked with javascript.

```
<input id="myHeader"/>

ChromeDriver driver = null;
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElementById("myHeader");
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```